# ReactJS componentDidMount, Fetch Spotify API and Promise

Tags: javascript, api, reactjs

I'm learning how used ReactJS, Spotify API, and Promise. I'm trying to fetch musician top albums on Spotify and play 30 seconds of the track.

I'm using a Spotify package called [spotify-web-api-node](https://github.com/JMPerez/spotify-web-api-js) I think I'm not understanding something fundamental about React or JS. `Syntax error: Unexpected token, expected ( (11:8)`

import React from 'react';

```
import SpotifyWebApi from 'spotify-web-api-node';
require('dotenv').config();


export default class SpotifyComponent extends React.Component {
  // Create the api object with the credentials
  const spotifyApi = new SpotifyWebApi({
    clientId : process.env.REACT_APP_SPOTIFY_CLIENT_ID,
    clientSecret : process.env.REACT_APP_SPOTIFY_CLIENT_SECRET
  });
// Save the access token so that it's used in future calls
  componentDidMount() {
    **(11:8)** --> return spotifyApi = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      spotifyApi.clientCredentialsGrant()

      .then( => (data) {
        console.log('The access token expires in ' + data.body['expires_in']);
        console.log('The access token is ' + data.body['access_token']);
      });

      // using Promises through Promise, Q or when - get Elvis' albums in range [20...29]
      spotifyApi.getArtistAlbums('43ZHCT0cAZBISjO8DG9PnE', {limit: 10, offset: 20})
        .then(function(data) {
          console.log('Album information', data);
        }, function(err) {
          console.error(err);
        });
    });

    SpotifyWebApi.setPromiseImplementation(Q);
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the specific problem?

Comment: I have update the code @jiargolisvt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have a `const` definition inside of a class like that.

You should either move it outside or remove the `const`:

```
// Create the api object with the credentials
const spotifyApi = new SpotifyWebApi({
  clientId : process.env.REACT_APP_SPOTIFY_CLIENT_ID,
  clientSecret : process.env.REACT_APP_SPOTIFY_CLIENT_SECRET
});

export default class SpotifyComponent extends React.Component {
```

or

```
export default class SpotifyComponent extends React.Component {
  // Create the api object with the credentials
  spotifyApi = new SpotifyWebApi({
    clientId : process.env.REACT_APP_SPOTIFY_CLIENT_ID,
    clientSecret : process.env.REACT_APP_SPOTIFY_CLIENT_SECRET
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

The way you're using the promises provided by the `spotify-api` are correct. However you shouldn't return a `Promise` from `componentDidMount`. `React` doesn't have any use for it.

Instead just run your promise based functions inside `componentDidMount`.

```
componentDidMount() {

  // the next line will actually trigger the promise to run
  spotifyApi.clientCredentialsGrant()
    .then((data) => { // this line was missing "=>" in your original code
      console.log('The access token expires in ' + data.body['expires_in']);
      console.log('The access token is ' + data.body['access_token']);
    });

  // the next line also triggers a promise to run
  spotifyApi.getArtistAlbums('43ZHCT0cAZBISjO8DG9PnE', {limit: 10, offset: 20})
    .then(function(data) {
      console.log('Album information', data);
    }, function(err) {
      console.error(err);
    });
}
```

Also you can set `Q` as the promise provider right after your import.

```
import SpotifyWebApi from 'spotify-web-api-node';
SpotifyWebApi.setPromiseImplementation(Q);
```

Comment: Thank you @Potorr

Comment: **question** getting an error message on  `const spotifyApi = new SpotifyWebApi({` this line saying that have `Syntax error: Unexpected token, expected ` How do I come by fixing this issue?

Comment: Also move that code out of your class, see answer by @Austin_Greco